# how to get clickable + sign and - sign corresponding to each row in data table plugin

Tags: datatables

i am using datatable plugin(https://datatables.net/) for dispalying data in frontend but unable to integrate the the clickable + sign that expands the table row andclickable minus sign that reverses the expansion as shown in data table plugin(https://datatables.net/).

Any suggestions.?

Comment: At least show us what you have tried

Comment: @BelalAwwad I haven't tried anything because i have no clue to which class to render or which class to select. I have provided the url,in that they have shown the demo for data table. I am able to apply data table but without the clickable + sign which are coming in the first column of the table.

Comment: See this : https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html

Comment: @BelalAwwad Thanks Belal , ithink this should work now.